# Is 'faithless' a literary version of 'unfaithful' (in the context of a spouse)?

Tags: synonyms, literary-english

Microsoft® Encarta® 2009. defines 'faithless' as:

> *faithless*, (of a spouse): unfaithful (**literary**)

Is 'faithless' really the literary term for 'unfaithful', unlike *unfaithful* which would supposedly be the most neutral one?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. What dictionary is this from? If  the dictionary says *faithless* can be used to mean unfaithful in literary usage, why do you question it?

Comment: What do you mean by “unless _unfaithful_”? Something is missing from that sentence. In the sense of ‘betraying the monogamy of a monogamous relationship’, yes, I’d say _faithless_ is definitely literary, old-fashioned, or high-faluting, whereas _unfaithful_ is perfectly commonplace. Both also mean ‘disloyal’, but in that sense, _unfaithful_ feels more old-fashioned to me, especially when talking about relationships.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet only faithless is shown in the following meaning : "dishonest: disloyal to somebody or something, e.g. in not keeping a promise or performing a duty" (Microsoft® Encarta® 2009.)

Comment: The only use of *faithless* that comes to my mind is in the phrase *faithless elector*, a member of the U.S. Electoral College (an entity with one task, formed for each Presidential election) who votes for a candidate other than the one for whom he was appointed to vote.

Comment: I thought Encarta would have used a definition from a dictionary. Either way there are at least 3 dictionaries freely available online whose definitions of "faithless" specifically mention "spouse", "wife" or "husband". So it's definitely not just something unique to Encarta.

Answer (score 2):

- a **faithless** person is a person without faith. For example, an atheist or nihilist or a person who believes in nothing. I would not say a wife or husband is faithless in terms of cheating on each other.
- a **faithful** person is a person who has faith towards others, often, a spouse, but not only. They have faith in someone or something. They are faithful to someone or something. A faithful friend is one who does not betray you.
- an **unfaithful** person is one who betrays the faith others have or had in them. If a wife or husband is unfaithful, they are breaking their marriage vows.
- a person can also be **unfaithful to something**. Unfaithful to an ideal,for example.

As for neutrality, that does not come into play here.

As for literary, they could all be said to be literary.

Comment: I was thinking exactly this. I have never heard *faithless* used in the sense of cheating on a spouse, but only in the sense of having a lack of faith in something or someone. (Of course, it could be a lack of faith in the marriage, but that's still different. *They are faithless when it comes to [believing in] their marriage, and so become unfaithful [to their spouse].*)

Comment: As far I'm concerned, it's an Encarta mistake. Thank you, Jason.

Comment: It's not just an Encarta quirk. I checked some dictionaries and at least two, Cambridge and American Heritage mention faith to a spouse or breaking trust of a spouse. Whether it's literary or not, I don't know. Though the 1913 edition of Webster's mentions "not of true fidelity; inconstant, as a husband or a wife", so maybe it's an older term. If it is, I wouldn't be surprised if it's considered "literary".

Comment: Of course, to be faithful/unfaithful to a spouse. But not to be "faithless" **to a spouse**.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the nuance differences of synonyms can be complicated because there can be a multitude of directions a difference can go, and the supporting resources (multiple dictionaries) can spell these differences out implicitly or explicitly but inadvertently imply things.

- ['unfaithful'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfaithful) is a common term with a few directions of meaning. One is untrustworty, one is disloyal, and another is about the romantic direction of 'cheating'.
- [faithless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faithless) is much less common, and to me means more like a person lacking faith in religion or leadership, a state of that person, rather than 'unfaithful' which is more about the target having done something wrong.

But I suppose if the lexicgrapher at Encarta had examples where it was used in belles lettres as meaning 'unfaithful' then I suppose that's OK. I only linked to M-W (which is strongly US biased) but other dictionaries corroborate.

If you want to use a word for 'cheating on a spouse' (but a little less bluntly) you probably want to use 'unfaithful' as 'faithless' is much less common and might be misleading if there's not enough context.

Answer (score 0):

In the famous collection of Welsh folktales, the Mabinogion, some of which I read when I was attempting to learn Welsh, there is a lady who is described, in Welsh, as 'fiddlos' - literally, faithless, and conventionally so translated.

That does not mean that she lacked religious faith, nor that she was occasionally unfaithful to her husband. What it meant was that she was constitutionally incapable of faithful attachment to anyone.  In BrE she might be described as 'flighty'.

In a literary context in English I would understand the word 'faithless' in that sense.